# Does CMake provide a way to run custom commands from the command line?

Tags: cmake

add_custom_command can be used to execute custom command, however CMake is responsible to call these commands when eg before the build or after the build.

What I am looking for is a way to launch a custom command from the command line, such as :

```
cmake --build
cmake --my_custom_command
```

Or

```
cmake --build
make --my_custom_command
```

The reason I want to do this is because I would like to :

- Create a command to launch by executable.
- Create a command which gathers all the necessary include paths from my executable dependencies.

Doing so would allow me to configure my editor without having to manually set these things per project.

Comment: Just create a *target* (with `add_custom_target`) and run it with `cmake --build --target <target_name>` or `make <target_name>`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Works perfectly, thanks !